# how to maintain a docker image with slight modifications?

Tags: docker

I've got a Docker image that is first built with a bunch of RUN commands that install software packages, dependencies, and copy files from a git repo. From this point forward, I want to create a new `latest` image only when the git repo is modified, but I don't want to repeat the entire process of installing the software. I just need to update the changed files and create the new image - so how does one create a image based on an existing image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build a named and tagged image, start a new Dockerfile with `FROM named:tagged`

Personally I do think that one should consider the same security practices for software inside containers as on other servers. Therfore I do suggest to at least run a full container update for every " latest" build.